# I am stuck on the executor function in promise constructor

Tags: javascript, promise

From the illustration of parameter executor of Promise constructor in MDN
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise
,I know the execution of executor is asynchronous.
When I resolve a value in executor,the promise resolved immediately,But how about resolve a resolved promise in executor? 
It is in pending state! Isn't the executor's execution asynchronous?
I am stuck on the resolve funtion in executor.
See the code below,Why is p1 in pending state?

```
var p3 = new Promise( function(resolve,reject){
    resolve( "B" );
} );

var p1 = new Promise( function(resolve,reject){
    resolve( p3 );
} );

var p2 = new Promise( function(resolve,reject){
    resolve( "A" );
} );

console.log(p3);  //Promise {<resolved>: "B"}
console.log(p1);  //Promise {<pending>}
console.log(p2);  //Promise {<resolved>: "A"}
```

Comment: [MDN :: Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) "The executor function is executed immediately by the Promise implementation"

Comment: yes, because of the microtask loop and resolving a promise with a promise will make the promise take on the value of the promise it is resolving to, but that is not don't "immediately", I mean, if you wrap the console.log's inside a 0 length setTimeout, p1 will be resolved, because the setTimeout will allow the microtask loop to resolve p1 to p3 before the "macrotask" of a settimeout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've essentially set things up so that the `p1` promise gets resolved with the resolved value of the `p3` promise.  But, the way you get any resolved value out of promise is you use `.then()`, so internally to `p1`, it's going to have to run `p3.then()` in order to get the resolved value.  But, `.then()` never happens immediately.  It always happens on a future tick of the event loop.  So your `console.log(p1)` happens before that future tick of the event loop that gets the value from `p3`.  Until that `p3.then()` runs, `p1` is still pending.

You can think of this code:

```
var p1 = new Promise( function(resolve,reject){
    resolve( p3 );
});
```

being like this:

```
var p1 = new Promise( function(resolve,reject){
    p3.then(function(val) {
        resolve(val);
    }, function(err) {
        reject(err);
    });
});
```

And, `p3.then()` always runs on a future tick of the event loop, not immediately.  So, `p1` remains in the `pending` state until that `p3.then()` handler gets called on a future tick of the event loop.

---

FYI, I'm hoping you know that `resolve(p3)` is generally an anti-pattern and this is just an academic exercise.  If the operation you're waiting on is already  a promise, there is no need to wrap it in another manually constructed promise (an anti-pattern).  Instead, you would just use the `p3` promise you already have, not wrap `p1` around it.

Comment: @林坤南 - Since it appears you may be new here, if this answered your question, then you can indicate that to the community by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer.  That will also earn you some reputation points for following the proper procedure here.